# Automatically encrypting everything image that enters into a specific folder

Tags: encryption

I would like to encrypt every image that goes into a specific folder with a public key, so that the image can't be opened from the phone and only be opened once I'm at my computer which has the private key. 
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please rephrase your question to exclude explicit app recommendation.

Comment: @AndyYan Whether it explicitly uses the word "app" or not doesn't make any difference: it's all about whether it's asking for recommendations or whether there's a specific problem to solve. You have to look past the surface content to see what kind of answers would fit the question.

Comment: If you really want to secure the images the app that writes it directly needs to write them encrypted. Otherwise the unencrypted data will be present n flash and can be recovered. Overwriting does not work with flash storage because of wear leveling.

Comment: @Robert : My thread model doesn't have the adversary do a hardware attack on the flash.

Comment: Have you checked the PGP/GPG apps? Monitoring a directory is pretty simple on Android therefore even if one of those apps does not have the monitoring feature the author/community may be willing to add it.

Comment: @DanHulme There's a reason you're a mod and I'm far from one :)